# Automatically fill column with DATETIME from other column while converting to different format

Tags: mysql, datetime, hex, concatenation, mysql-workbench

I have a table in a MySQL database with time data coming into the database (cannot change this format) encoded such that when the value is converted into hexadecimal I get time in the format yymmddhh as in:

```
538050839 = 20120117
```

What I need is `'2020-12-01 17:00:00'` to be filled automatically into the `Time` column in the table with a create statement like the one below

```
CREATE TABLE Example(SomeData INT ,SomeOtherData INT, TimeWrongFormat INT, Time DATETIME )
```

How can I convert the data into hex and also format it as a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Example (
    SomeData INT,
    SomeOtherData INT, 
    TimeWrongFormat INT, 
    TimeCorrectFormat DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE(CONV(TimeWrongFormat, 10, 16), '%y%c%d%H'))
);
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31f17e466310fa4e898f13fd9e647e1c)

PS. The `TimeWrongFormat` value format must match the pattern strictly (i.e. always must contain only date and hour parts and not contain min/sec parts). If it may vary then the expression must be more complex.